# ServiceStack Authentication You don't need to use IHttpRequest.TryResolve<IHttpRequest> to resolve itself

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I am trying to create a service that automatically logs the user into the system by using the `AuthenticateService`. *(ServiceStack v4.0.8.0)*

`AppHost` Configuration:

```cs
//Plugins
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] { new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider() }));

container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

My `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider`:

```cs
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        // Custom Auth Logic
        // Return true if credentials are valid, otherwise false
        // bool isValid = Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

        var loginManager = authService.TryResolve<LoginManager>();
        var loginInfo = loginManager.GetLoginInfo(session.UserAuthName);

        authService.SaveSession(loginInfo.CustomUserSession, SessionExpiry);
    }
}
```

My `TestService`:

```cs
public class TestService : Service
{       
    public object Any(Test request)
    {
        var response = new TestResponse();

        var authService = base.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>();            
        var authResponse = authService.Authenticate(new Authenticate
        {
            UserName = "user",
            Password = "password",
            RememberMe = false
        });           

        return response;
    }
}
```

When I run this, the authService resolves and the code in the `TryAuthenticate()` and `OnAuthenticated()` methods executes without errors.

Finally when it returns the response and renders the page in the browser I see this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> You don't need to use IHttpRequest.TryResolve to resolve
>   itself
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: You don't need to use
>   IHttpRequest.TryResolve to resolve itself
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:

```cs
[Exception: You don't need to use IHttpRequest.TryResolve<IHttpRequest> to resolve itself]   
ServiceStack.Host.AspNet.AspNetRequest.TryResolve() +194   
ServiceStack.Formats.MarkdownFormat.GetPageName(Object dto, IRequestrequestContext) +94   
ServiceStack.Formats.MarkdownFormat.SerializeToStream(IRequest request, Object response, Stream stream) +284   
ServiceStack.Host.<>c__DisplayClass2.<GetResponseSerializer>b__1(IRequest httpReq, Object dto, IResponse httpRes) +92   
ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.WriteToResponse(IResponse response, Object result, ResponseSerializerDelegate defaultAction,
IRequest request, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix) +2477

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]   
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +3650617   
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +10816173   
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() +10
ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +83   
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

The `base.ResolveService<T>` should already be setting the `Request` context in the `AuthenticateService`.  But just in case I tried this as well.

```cs
var authService = base.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>();
authService.Request = this.Request;
```

Result: same error message.

I also tried this:

```cs
var authService = base.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>();
authService.Request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ToRequest();
```

Result: With this I do not get any errors, and I see the TestResponse! Also, I get back the "ss-id" and "ss-pid" cookies.

I would have stopped here, but even though I have the cookies if I make a request to a service that has the `[Authenticate]` attribute.  I get this:

> Handler for Request not found:
>   Request.HttpMethod: GET 
>   Request.PathInfo: /login 
>   Request.QueryString: ServiceStack.NameValueCollectionWrapper
>   Request.RawUrl: /login?redirect=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50063%2fBOP%2fbasic-info-2

So it is not authenticating properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok looks like there's a bug in v4.08 [fixed in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/b6708b91594aa20da8bd43c219edac7966748734).

To work around this you can manually reset the ResponseContentType, e.g:

```
public class TestService : Service
{       
    public object Any(Test request)
    {
        var response = new TestResponse();

        var authService = base.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>();            
        var authResponse = authService.Authenticate(new Authenticate
        {
            UserName = "user",
            Password = "password",
            RememberMe = false
        });           

        base.Request.ResponseContentType = MimeTypes.Html;

        return response;
    }
}
```

You can ignore this workaround in v4.09+, which you [can now get on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Thanks! I just tested the temporary workaround and it resolved that first error.  However, after I call the TestService and log the user in successfully (I get the ss-id and ss-pid cookies), and then I try to hit a service that has the [Authenticate] attribute I get the handler for request not found as it tried to redirect me to /login.  I think it would be best to break that into a separate question which I will do next.

Comment: Here is the link to the second part of this question with more detail.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482929/servicestack-authentication-authenticate-attribute-fails-to-process-the-ss-id

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I attacked this another way.  I created an attribute that you put on your service like this:

```cs
[ServiceStackToAspNetAuthorize(Roles = "somerole")]
```

It uses asp.net to determine if you are in that role, if you are logged in.  Here is the attribute code.

```cs
public class ServiceStackToAspNetAuthorizeAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    private string _roles;
    private string[] _rolesSplit = new string[0];

    public string Roles
    {
        get { return _roles ?? String.Empty; }
        set
        {
            _roles = value;
            _rolesSplit = SplitString(value);
        }
    }

    public ServiceStackToAspNetAuthorizeAttribute(ApplyTo applyTo)
        : base(applyTo)
    {
        this.Priority = (int)RequestFilterPriority.Authenticate;
    }

    public ServiceStackToAspNetAuthorizeAttribute()
        : this(ApplyTo.All) { }


    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        if (!InternalAuthorize())
        {
            res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            res.EndRequest();
        }
    }

    private bool InternalAuthorize()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context != null)
        {
            var user = context.User;
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    return false;
                if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole))
                    return false;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static string[] SplitString(string original)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
        {
            return new string[0];
        }

        var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                    let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                    where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                    select trimmed;
        return split.ToArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: I gave them another way to do the authentication Scott.  If it did not help them, that is fine, it was just another way to do it.

Comment: I guess, now that I re-read the question, you are right.  However, I answered this because the original backstory of this question started on the private servicestack forums for paying customers.  On there he spoke of his trying to map security between SS and asp.net sessions.

Comment: I did not see the OP response, I just saw the conversation moved here and was trying to 'move' it here.  Down vote - no worries, that matters little to me :-)  Thanks Scott.

Comment: Absolutely, no worries.  See you around SS!