# ServiceStack Authentication [Authenticate] Attribute Fails to Process the ss-id and ss-pid

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I created a TestService that calls the `AuthenticateService` and authenticates the user.  Before calling the TestService I cleared all of my cookies to make sure that once I get the response I get the `ss-id` and `ss-pid` cookies, which I do get.

`AppHost` Configuration: (SS v4.0.8.0)

```cs
//Plugins
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] { new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider() }));

container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
```

My `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider`:

```cs
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        // Custom Auth Logic
        // Return true if credentials are valid, otherwise false
        // bool isValid = Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

        var loginManager = authService.TryResolve<LoginManager>();
        var loginInfo = loginManager.GetLoginInfo(session.UserAuthName);

        authService.SaveSession(loginInfo.CustomUserSession, SessionExpiry);
    }
}
```

My `TestService`:

```cs
public class TestService : Service
{       
    public object Any(Test request)
    {
        var response = new TestResponse();

        var authService = base.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>();            
        var authResponse = authService.Authenticate(new Authenticate
        {
            UserName = "user",
            Password = "password",
            RememberMe = false
        });           

        base.Request.ResponseContentType = MimeTypes.Html;  //Temporary workaround, will not be needed in v4.0.9+

        return response;
    }
}
```

So, to recap.  I hit the TestService, authenticate the user, return response and make sure the response contains the `ss-id` and `ss-pid` cookies.  Now I try to hit another service that has the `[Authenticate]` attribute.  My breakpoint in the service never hits and I get this response in the browser.

> Handler for Request not found:
>
> Request.HttpMethod: GET   Request.PathInfo: /login 
>   Request.QueryString: ServiceStack.NameValueCollectionWrapper
>   Request.RawUrl:/login?redirect=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a50063%2fBOP%2fbasic-info-2

I have tried applying the `[Authenticate]` attribute over the service method and over the whole service, with the same result.  I have tested that I can get to the service methods if the `[Authenticate]` attribute is commented out, which works, so it is not service config issue or route issue.

I also created two service methods `/basic-info-1` and `/basic-info-2`.  `/basic-info-2` has the `[Authenticate]` attribute and `basic-info-1` does not.  After authenticating, I am able to get to `basic-info-1` without issues and have also confirmed that I can get to the session information that was saved in the `OnAuthenticated()` method.  For `/basic-info-2` I get that handler error.

I am not sure what happens in the `[Authenticate]` attribute but from the looks of that handler error, the authentication fails and SS tries to redirect me to `/login` which does not exist in my project hence the handler error.  I wonder why the authenticate attribute is not recognizing my `ss-id` and `ss-pid` cookies?

Comment: You have said the you have confirmed the ss-id and ss-pid cookies are in the response from your Test service. Have you confirmed they are send by your client in the subsequent requests? Can you post the code making the calls to `/basic-info-1` and `-2`?

Comment: I am just using the browser (chrome).  So there is no code.  It is just basic GET requests to /test, /basic-info-1, /basic-info-2.  Before I made the first request to /test I cleared my cookies to make sure that when the request completes, I can see the cookies via the debug tools.

Comment: If you set breakpoints in your `TryAuthenticate` and `OnAuthenticated` methods, do they get hit after the request to `/Test`? In your action method for `/basic-info-1` if you break and examine `base.Request` do you see the cookies in the request object?

Comment: Yes the TryAuthenticate and OnAuthenticated methods get hit and my session values get set.  When I break and examine the base.Request.Cookies in /basic-info-1 I see 2 cookies ss-id and ss-pid with the same values that I saw in the browser dev tools.  I can also access the session information inside /basic-info-1.

Comment: Instead of calling your `/Test` method can you try this navigating to `http://yourserver:port/auth/login?UserName=user&Password=password&RememberMe=false&x-http-method-override=post` in your browser. Substitute in your server address, port and username and password. This will call the authentication in the intended way. Then call `/basic-info-2` and see if the `[Authenticate]` attribute is working or not. If not I suspect there is an issue with the retention of the Session, in that the server is issuing a session Id but not storing it, so it's not valid when you come back with subsequent reqs.

Comment: I called the /auth/login... and everything went through the same.  The only difference I noticed was that I got 3 cookies instead of 2.  The new one is the ss-opt.  Hitting /basic-info-2 still returned the same handler for request not found.  Hitting /basic-info-1 worked fine, I could see all 3 cookies in the base.Request.Cookies and I could access my session information.

Comment: When you get the session in `/basic-info-1` can you see `UserAuthId`, `UserAuthName` and `Id` correctly set?

Comment: WOW!  No they were all NULL.  So I created the CustomUserSession: AuthUserSession class.  In the OnAuthenticated() method I introduced a LoginManager class that returned a new instance of CustomUserSession and then I was saving that.  So, basically I had been overriding the values that got populated in the AuthUserSession.  So, this was all my fault.  What I think really threw me off was the fact that the values that I had saved as part of the CustomUserSession were still available on subsequent requests so I assumed the session was working just fine.  Thanks a lot Scott!

Comment: I wonder if I should close or delete this question?  What do you think Scott?  Although it was a blunder on my end, it could be helpful to someone who is setting up a CustomUserSession.  Just to make sure that the values in the base class AuthUserSession get persisted when calling the SaveSession() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Diagnosis:

You should check the session being returned in your unauthenticated method (`/basic-info-1`), after you have authenticated using `/test`. If your session is working correctly you should see `UserAuthId`, `UserAuthName` and `Id` correctly set on the session. It doesn't appear these are correctly set and the `[Authenticate]` attribute therefore doesn't see a valid session.

### Likely Problem:

The problem is likely in your `OnAuthenticated` method, specifically your `LoginManager` is not correctly returning these values when you save the session.

From your code:

```
var loginManager = authService.TryResolve<LoginManager>();
var loginInfo = loginManager.GetLoginInfo(session.UserAuthName); 

authService.SaveSession(loginInfo.CustomUserSession, SessionExpiry);
```

- `loginInfo.CustomUserSession.UserAuthId` is `null`
- `loginInfo.CustomUserSession.UserAuthName` is `null`
- `loginInfo.CustomUserSession.Id` is `null`

### Solution:

Correctly set those attributes before calling `SaveSession`.